# Using a select field on a page edit screen to choose a repeater row to display

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

On multiple pages of a site I'm building, we have a "call to action" - an image, headline, paragraph, and button with link. The designer would like the client to have the ability to 1) add, edit, and remove these CTAs from a list; 2) use a select field on a specific page's edit screen to choose which CTA they would like to be displayed on the page at a given time.

I can build a repeater on an options page with these CTAs. My question is, how can I link those repeater rows to a select field, and then output the selection as a fully populated div on the page itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I would make a [Custom Post Type](https://generatewp.com/post-type/) for the CTAs and than use ACF ['Post Object'](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/post-object/) to select which CTA to use on each page.

Comment: Ah, that totally makes sense. Thank you!